# Android XML not well formed

Tags: android, xml, layout

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/droid_background"
>
 <TextView  
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:text="@string/hello"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textStyle="bold"
>
<RelativeLayout>
<ToggleButton
android:id="@+id/togglebutton1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:text="Audio"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
>
</RelativeLayout>
</TableLayout>'
```

Getting error XML parsing: not well formed between The opening `<ToggleButton>` and closing `</RelativeLayout>`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

you are missing closing tags or / on TextView & ToggleButton

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to have closing tags for the `<TextView>` and `<ToggleButton>`.

You would benefit from spending a bit of time reading about basic XML document structure. In particular, XML needs to be *well-formed*. Here's a good tutorial:

http://www.javacommerce.com/displaypage.jsp?name=wellform.sql&id=18238

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<TableLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/droid_background" >  
    <TextView   
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:text="@string/hello" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
        android:textStyle="bold" /> 
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" > 
        <ToggleButton 
            android:id="@+id/togglebutton1" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Audio" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  /> 
    </LinearLayout> 
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't mean to have the quotes there, you need to end your TextViews and Toggle Butotns.

Try to look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Change your code to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/droid_background"
>
 <TextView  
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:text="@string/hello"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textStyle="bold"
 />
<RelativeLayout>
<ToggleButton
android:id="@+id/togglebutton1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:text="Audio"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
 />
</RelativeLayout>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: i tried to close it like </Textview> and </ToggleButton> whatever the quick inserts are then it says Must be close with a > or /> so I've done that in the above. And it still don't like it.

Comment: Also, I am not sure that `TableLayout` can be used as a LayoutRoot(the first declaration). I would try wrapping all of that in a `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't closed ToggleButton and TextView tag. Take attention to that always. Thats common mistake use

```
    <ToggleButton />
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/droid_background" >
 <TextView  
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:text="@string/hello"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textStyle="bold" />
<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ToggleButton
android:id="@+id/togglebutton1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:text="Audio"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
</TableLayout>'
```

your relative layout must have height and width properties

Answer (score 0):

you should close the balise ToggleButton , there is two ways to do it :

`<ToggleButton......... > </ToggleButton>`   OR   `<ToggleButton ........./>`

the same thing for the `TextView` , so verify all of your views when coding :)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

replace your toggle code with that (ie close it) and add a closing for the text view () depending on what is nested inside the textview.